# Autocompletion doesn't autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, local-storage, forms

[Here is a page](http://5.135.181.77/test/autocomplete.html) with:

```
<form action="action.php" method="get" autocomplete="on">
  First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Let's enter the 2 fields, and submit. Then when reloading the page, the fields **are not autocompleted**, why?

Should I use local-storage? cookies? to be sure that a user that comes back a few days after will still have its fields autocompleted?

*(I'm using Firefox with default options about autocompletion, i.e. not disabled).*

Comment: why do you think it would autocomplete?

Comment: Google chrome: here it works.

Comment: @jcuenod `<form ...autocomplete="on">`. Is [this doc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_autocomplete.asp) completely wrong?

Comment: @Basj W3schools is usually wrong, but anyway its working in chrome.

Comment: @Pogrindis I know, but... *so wrong* ?

Comment: @Pogrindis correction: "w3schools"

Comment: @Jordumus If possible, can you test on Firefox ?

Comment: It's working on both Google Chrome and FireFox. (And I've never seen W3Schools wrong) And BTW, the `autocomplete` attribute, is `on` by default. Autocomplete is when you can see your previous values by double-clicking the form inputs.

Comment: @Seblor Oh maybe I used a wrong word by using **autocompletion** ? I don't mean populating a list... I just want that a user that comes back has the fields "pre-filled" with last values.

Comment: @Basj if you just want it filled, then by all means use localstorage. Your implementation is correct.

Comment: @Basj I've updated my answer to help you a little more with your prefilling plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to realise that an attribute on the element without any coding on your part is entirely browser implemented.

Browsers implement these things differently.

You should check [the spec](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text). There you will notice that, actually,

> By default, the autocomplete attribute of form elements is in the on state.

The only solution to the problem you are having is to say that, if you want a more reliable and consistent, user experience; don't rely on browser implementation.

The short answer: Use Javascript

There are hundreds of plugins that will do this for you. I will point you to one that has been popular on github recently but will need you to actually need to tell this plugin what you expect it to do: https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/

**Updated Answer:**

I see that you just want to prefill the field. This can be accomplished with something like this (untested):

```
var form = document.forms["name_of_your_form"];
form.onsubmit = function(){
  localStorage.setItem("fname", form.elements["fname"].value);
  localStorage.setItem("email", form.elements["email"].value);
}
window.onload = function() {
  form.elements["fname"].value = localStorage.getItem("fname");
  form.elements["email"].value = localStorage.getItem("email");
}
```

Comment: Why do you say `without any coding on your part` ? I have set `autocomplete=on` for the whole form.

Comment: How would you do it then if you want to be sure that autocompletion works? Local-storage? Cookies?

Comment: @Basj that depends how you want to store the posted input values from the form, how you populate the list then for that user is up to you, but you will need javascript. You want to store the info on the client though of course. So localstorage is an option, as is cookies.

Comment: @Basj I've updated my answer to point to an autocomplete plugin but I guess storing suggestions in localstorage is not a bad idea (and connecting the localstorage to the autocomplete thing you end up using).